# Is there way to render HTML and js as a request in jmeter?

Tags: javascript, html, jmeter

I am getting HTML body in response(Please see attached snapshot). It is having a hidden form and a internal java script to submit the same form.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYnAK.png)

Is there any way in jmeter to run java script which will directly submit form.

I am trying to sort out this issue using JSR223 Post processor and sampler. Since response is HTML document, getting challenge to implement the same.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is not like Browser. So it can not run the javascript. JMeter can submit the form only if you add the corresponding HTTP Sampler request in your test plan.

That is, Record your actions on the browser like Chrome using JMeter. If you have done the form submission, JMeter would have recorded that as well. Now JMeter can play back and simulate the behavior.

Comment: As you suggested, I have already added in test plan.I just want to understand is there any way to run that js using scripting sampler (JSR223/bean shell) so that http request can be automated.

Comment: You can run js in general. But you can not access the browser DOM as chrome / firefox does. So you can not in this case.